# Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate

Tags: php, ubuntu

Al lanzar el comando:

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Me sale el error:

> ```
> Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate
> ```

¿sabéis cómo solucionarlo?

He seguido este post y nada.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04/756186#756186

Answer (score 0):

Esta diciendo que ese paquete no existe.

El que debes instalar es `5.6`, quedando lo que debes ejecutar de la siguiente manera:

```
apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
```

Comment: Si bien la respuesta es correcta, puede que el OP haya omitido alguno de los pasos. Es muy importante validar que primero ejecute los siguientes comandos en este orden: 1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, 2. `sudo apt-get update` y 3. `apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt`.

Comment: @Marcos o bien `sudo apt-get -y install php5.6-pgsql php5.6-cli php5.6-curl php5.6-json php5.6-sqlite3 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-curl php-xdebug php5.6-mbstring libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0 mysql-server-5.7 apache2` asegurando la instalación de cada paquete de dicha versión.

Comment: Si no haces los primeros 2 pasos, puede que ninguno de los paquetes que mencionas se intale, ya que no se ha registrado el repositorio y actualizado `apt-get`.

Comment: @Marcos yo ejecuto esa tira desde linux mint 16 y se instala sin ningún problema todo `php5.6`, de igual forma tendré presente tu comentario para el futuro. Gracias.